# Elastic Beanstalk AWS Powershell Migration Tool not creating application because no VPC is chosen

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I Have an on premises api running on IIS, and I'm using the AWS Migration tool to move my applications to Elastic beanstalk (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-onpremmigration.html).
here is the powershell script (https://github.com/awslabs/windows-web-app-migration-assistant/blob/master/MigrateIISWebsiteToElasticBeanstalk.ps1)

I followed all the steps on the ps1 script, however when the application is being created on elastic beanstalk it's cancelled due to a VPC not being chosen.

I checked and I can create new elastic IPs as it's written on the Read.me
Is there a way I can add this parameter?

Because when I check the beanstalk application configuration, on network I can't edit to add a VPC on it

During the script there are some prompt you do, but none of them is to chose a VPC, I looked through the script but couldn't find where I could set or even how I could set a VPC for my elestic beanstalk.

Can someone help me find a way to edit this script or even know if there is any configuration I should do on amazon to be able to run this script?

Here are the logs of error from my Elastic Beanstalk
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM6wY.png

Comment: Do you have a default VPC in your region? EB will use default VPC if custom one is not provided. Maybe you don't have a default VPC, thus EB errors out?

Comment: I have Verified and I don't have a default VPN set in this region, the problem is that I can't create a default VPN because it was deleted and another VPN was created with the default IP value.

So I can't delete the current VPN that has the defaul IP and I can't create a default VPN

Comment: So when creating the EB env, you have set up VPC and subnets where to launch your instances.

Comment: That is the question, how do I make this in that script? what type of line do I need to add?